# Embed Python in C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, embed

This may be a duplicate idk. I searched for answers and none helped me.
Im trying to embed Python in C++ in Visual Studio 2017. My Goal is to run this:

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main()
{
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

What im doing is:
install the nuget paket "python-embed" for the project
i add ...\packages\python-embed.3.6.1.1\lib\native\include to additional includes
i add ...\packages\python-embed.3.6.1.1\lib\native\libs\python36.lib to additional dependencies
copy the code above, build <strike>and run</strike>

i get the following errors:
1>PYxC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Initialize
1>PYxC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags
1>PYxC.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Finalize
1>C:\Users\Windows\source\repos\PYxC\Release\PYxC.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved external

can somebody please explain to sombebody with a low iq how to embed python in c++ in visual studio 2017 as in the code above or as in this https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding

Comment: The error means that it is not able to find library code for the used functions like `Py_Initialize`, i.e. it is not able to find `python36.lib` (or maybe python36.lib doesn't have the functions). One thing that is odd is that you are referring to python 2.x docs, but try to embed python 3.6

Comment: Nevermind, the [3.x version](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) looks similar. So how did you add python36.lib to the project? You need to add it to "link additional libraries" section in the project settings.

Comment: not the op, but I have the same problem. I linked the python36.lib file and still the build is not successful. Is there anything else I should check ?